# How to open playstore's main/home page programmatically?

Tags: android, android-intent, uri, start-activity

I'm trying to open playstore app but I don't want to open any app in it instead I just want to open playstore's main/home page.

For that, I tried this:

```
try {
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://")));
} catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://")));
}
```

but this code is not working for me.

How can I open the playstore's main/home page?

Comment: https://play.google.com/store                              add this url in try block

Comment: @harshpatel that was easy. Silly me!

Comment: You can try this Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps")